# What is the max room size?

Tags: pewdiepie-tuber-simulator

What is the max room size, and how much does it cost for each upgrade?

Considering that every upgrade would add 1 unit to the side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So far, I have found that you can at least increase it by 5 units (a unit being half the length of the purple square rug which you unlock early on in the game) - with the price for increasing the size being 10, 25, 50, 75 and then 100.

I have not increased the room to have five extra units yet in one direction, but I have a feeling from looking at PewDiePie's own room as it is right now, it might be six extra units.

Here are a few images to try and measure what it actually is:

[image: Normal sized room, zoomed out][image: The same room, with one unit added to the left wall][image: PewDiePie's current room]

Comment: I'm right next to buying the 100 upgrade, I'll see if it locks afterwards. If it does, this is the right answer.

Comment: Well, if it doesn't yet the one after that locks it, then it is still correct in a way - it just will need editing. And besides, it does look like PewDiePie's room has six extra.